# NextAuthJs - Can't return session.user.id

Tags: authentication, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'am currently creating a new next14 project using prisma.

I have this code  to manage nextAuth:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const githubId = process.env.AUTH_GITHUB_ID;
const githubSecret = process.env.AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET;

if (!githubId || !githubSecret) {
  throw new Error('no githubid or secret');
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: githubId,
      clientSecret: githubSecret,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.name = user.name;
      session.user.image = user.image;
      session.user.id = user.id;

      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

And session alway can be undefined and Id doesnt existe on session.user.id

I have this package

```
"@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.11",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.10.2",
```

I alson have another on folder to get my session easyli durring the project and session also can be undefined (I had the same file for another project and it worked :

```
import {
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  NextApiRequest,
  NextApiResponse,
} from 'next';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';

type ParametersGetServerSession =
  | []
  | [GetServerSidePropsContext['req'], GetServerSidePropsContext['res']]
  | [NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse];

export const getAuthSession = async (
  ...parameters: ParametersGetServerSession
) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(...parameters, authOptions);
  return session;
};
export const getRequiredAuthSession = async (
  ...parameters: ParametersGetServerSession
) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(...parameters, authOptions);
  if (!session?.user.id) {
    throw new Error('Unhautorized');
  }
  return session as {
    user: {
      id: string;
      email?: string;
      image?: string;
      name?: string;
    };
  };
};

If I do await getServerSession(authOptions) I can get my user informations AND id after connecting.
```

I already did almost the same thing for another one project with :

```
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter';
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import { env } from '@/lib/env';

const githubId = process.env.GITHUB_ID;
const githubSecret = process.env.GITHUB_SECRET;

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),

  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.name = user.name;
      session.user.image = user.image;
      session.user.id = user.id;

      return session;
    },
  },
};

    export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

I had this package :

```
  "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.11",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^0.4.4-canary.81",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.7.1",
```

You can find my repos :

repo with error : https://github.com/NocerGal/Dix-Cordes/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts

repo that works : https://github.com/NocerGal/Blog-Next/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts

I am on this error for now one day, I don't know how to manage it. I saw people seem online having this kind on issue, but not with session.